# How to setup Airplay on a headless Raspberry Pi using OSMC over ssh

Tags: ssh, audio, osmc

I want to use my Raspberry Pi as an headless (no monitor, no keyboard) Airplay receiver to stream sound to my speakers.

How can I set up [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) over ssh to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airplay is installed and activated by default on OSMC.

All you have to do is install OSMC on your Raspberry Pi and setup the audio output to direct it to your analogue speakers, as it is set on HDMI audio by default:

1. [Download the OSMC installer](https://osmc.tv/download/) for your OS
2. Run the executable to install OSMC on an SD card and setup the network connection
3. Plug in your Raspberry Pi, equipped with the SD card
4. Locate the IP address of your Raspberry Pi in your network (typically this is done by checking the leases on your DHCP server)
5. `ssh osmc@the-ip-address`, default password: `osmc`
6. Turn off kodi: `sudo systemctl stop mediacenter`
7. Set the audio output to analogue: `nano ~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml`. In this file, locate the line:

   `<audiodevice default="true">PI:HDMI</audiodevice>`

   and replace it with:

   `<audiodevice>PI:Analogue</audiodevice>`

   Save and exit (`Ctrl+X`, `y`)
8. Restart kodi: `sudo systemctl start mediacenter`

You're done! You can now stream Airplay to your Raspberry Pi!